# WordPress Permalink with custom post type and custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called product and a custom taxonomy for products called product_types, which is hierarchical, so I have sub-categories in it.

I want the permalink to show up as http://mysite.com/product_type/sub_category/postname

I tried a lot of plugins and things I found online, nothing worked so far.

Thank you.

Comment: See also: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Permalink+custom+post+type+custom+taxonomy

Comment: Yes, I did search, none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a useful description. Enable the debug mode and write down what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Okay, it did not work - nothing changed, no errors or anything. It just won't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly I would double check the function which is creating your custom post type, 
within that function there should be an element called: rewrite

ie:

```
register_post_type( 'products',
   'menu_position' => 25, // below pages
   'public' => true,
   'show_ui' => true,
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product' ) <-- this is what you need!
);
```

also check the register_taxonomy function for the same!

ie:

```
 register_taxonomy(
  'team',array('product_types'), 
    array(
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, <-- this is needed!
    'rewrite' => true <-- this is what you need!
  ));
```

the only thing left to check is:

your permalink structure is set to /%postname%/
you may have to reset to default, save it, 
then re-set to /%postname%/ and save,

hope that helps :)

Marty

Comment: are you creating the custom post type via functions.php or are you using a plugin to do this for you?

Comment: I am using the functions.php - how is this relevant ?

Comment: while using functions.php you have more control over how your custom post types are created, can you add the code your using to built your custom post type and the register taxonomy code to the question above to have a more indepth look..M