# Wordpress - Custom Taxonomy in Permalink for Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I have a Custom Post Type called **destination** and a custom taxonomy named **regions** (with terms like *asia, europe, africa*, etc.) I created a destination (**venice**) and had it associated with a region (**europe**). Now I have been trying for hours to get the CPT's permalink to work like `/%region%/%destination%` (e.g. http://example.com/europe/venice) but it keeps giving me **404 Not found**. This is the relevant code:

```
add_action("init", "register_region_taxonomy");
add_action("init", "create_destinations_post_type");
add_filter("post_type_link", "region_permalink", 10, 3);
```

This is how I created my custom taxonomy:

```
function register_region_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => _x("Destination Region", "taxonomy general name"),
        "singular_name" => _x("Region", "taxonomy singular name"),
        "search_items" => __("Search Regions"),
        "popular_items" => __("Popular Regions"),
        "all_items" => __("All Regions"),
        "parent_item" => null,
        "parent_item_colon" => null,
        "edit_item" => __("Edit Region"),
        "update_item" => __("Update Region"),
        "add_new_item" => __("Add New Region"),
        "new_item_name" => __("New Region"),
        "separate_items_with_commas" => __("Separate regions with commas"),
        "add_or_remove_items" => __("Add or remove regions"),
        "choose_from_most_used" => __("Choose from the most used regions"),
        "menu_name" => __("Regions"),
    );

    register_taxonomy("regions", "destination", array(
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "labels" => $labels,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_admin_column" => true,
        "update_count_callback" => "_update_post_term_count",
        "query_var" => "region",
        "rewrite" => array("slug" => "region"),
    ));
}
```

This is my custom post type:

```
function create_destinations_post_type() {

    register_post_type("destination",
        // CPT Options
        array(
            "labels" => array(
                "name" => __("destinations"),
                "singular_name" => __("destination")
            ),
            "public" => true,
            "publicly_queryable" => true,
            "has_archive" => true,
            "show_ui" => false,
                "not_found" => "No destinations Found",
            "rewrite" => array("slug" => "%region%", "with_front" => false)
            )
    );
}
```

This is how I expect it to change my permalink for destinations:

```
function region_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, "%region%") === FALSE)
        return $permalink;

    // Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post)
        return $permalink;

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, "regions");

    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    else
        $taxonomy_slug = "no-region";

    return str_replace("%region%", $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

I followed [this article](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks) step-by-step but to no avail. I tried going to *Permalink settings* page and saving it again - as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296959/wordpress-permalink-with-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy) - but to no effect (my permalink settings are set to **Post name**). I tried calling `flush_rewrite_rules()` right after creating my CPT but nope, it just wont work. I'm not sure if I was able to correctly use [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698827/custom-permalink-structure-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post-name) because I altered the solution like this:

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", "add_destination_rewrite_rules");

function add_destination_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new = array();
    $new['([^/]+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?destination=$matches[1]';
    $new['(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?region=$matches[0]';

    return array_merge($new, $rules); // Ensure our rules come first
}
```

No success still, so I've reverted that change for now.

If I try http://example.com/venice it indeed enters the permalink hook and the URL on my browser changes to http://example.com/europe/venice but ultimately it shows me that wicked 404 page. Any clues to what I'm doing wrong here? My .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wpsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```