# custom post type category permalink to /%category%/%postname%/

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have already created portfolio as an custom post types. I want make permalink only for custom post types like: `www.domain.com/custom-post-type-category/postname`

Current permalink is : `www.domain.com/custom-post-type/postname`

It's totally custom post oriented only.

```
if(!function_exists("pexeto_register_portfolio_post_type")){
    function pexeto_register_portfolio_post_type() {

        //the labels that will be used for the portfolio items
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'portfolio name', 'pexeto'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'portfolio type singular name', 'pexeto'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio', 'pexeto'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item', 'pexeto'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Item', 'pexeto'),
            'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item', 'pexeto'),
            'view_item' => __('View Item', 'pexeto'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio Items', 'pexeto'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No portfolio items found', 'pexeto'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No portfolio items found in Trash', 'pexeto'), 
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

        //register the custom post type
        register_post_type( PEXETO_PORTFOLIO_POST_TYPE,
            array( 'labels' => $labels,
             'public' => true,  
             'show_ui' => true,  
             'capability_type' => 'post',  
             'hierarchical' => false,  
             'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'portfolio'),
             'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category'),
             'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'page-attributes') ) );
    }
}

if(!function_exists("pexeto_register_portfolio_category")){
    function pexeto_register_portfolio_category(){

        register_taxonomy("portfolio_category",
        array(PEXETO_PORTFOLIO_POST_TYPE),
        array(  "hierarchical" => true,
            "label" => "Portfolio Categories", 
            "singular_label" => "Portfolio Categories", 
            "rewrite" => true,
            "query_var" => true
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress Permalink with custom post type and custom taxonomy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296959/wordpress-permalink-with-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy)

Comment: Not working, Its custom-post-type-category/postname

Comment: CPT category = taxonomy

Comment: Not, Working. I'm using theme of PEXETO

Comment: Provide your CPT definition in your question then.

Comment: Its added kindly check it.

Comment: You need to set hierarchical to true, as pointed out in the duplicate.

Comment: but it's not working dude.

Comment: How the permalinks are set in Settings > Reading ?

Comment: Its 404 pages error here. /%postname%/

Comment: Same here, It's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the following to change all the URL from `:post-type:/:post-name:` to `:post-category:/:post-name:`:

```
function portfolio_post_link($post_link, $post, $leavename) {
    if($post->post_type == 'portfolio') {
        $category_slug = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_category');
        $category_slug = is_array($category_slug) ? '/' . $category_slug[0]->slug . '/' : '/';
        $post_link = str_replace('/'.$post->post_type.'/', $category_slug, $post_link);
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'portfolio_post_link', 10, 3);
```

But it will not be enough - you will need to tell wordress how to handle those new urls. I suggest to try first the code above and see if you get a 404 with those new urls. If so, you will have to add some rewrite rules or use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action.